# 期間を含むDataFrameの条件抽出

Tags: python, pandas

以下のような期間を含むDataFrameで、指定した日付が期間内に含まれる行を抽出するには、どうしたらよいでしょうか？
例えば、'2021/08/05'を検索条件としたとき、りんごの行を抽出することは可能でしょうか？（applyや行ループするしかないのでしょうか？）
よろしくお願いします。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={ '品名':[ 'りんご', 'バナナ', 'みかん' ] },
    index=[
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/08/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/08/10')),
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/09/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/09/10')),
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/10/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/10/10')) ]
)
display(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pandas.IntervalIndex.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.contains.html)あたりの応用で以下のように出来そうです。

```
selected = df[df.index.contains('2021/08/05')]
```

---

何で`pd.Timestamp('2021/08/01 00:01')`を使った回答されたか不思議だったのですが、上記方法だと'2021/08/01'の時に検出出来ないからですね。
これはDataFrame作成時の指定方法が関係していると考えられます。

```
pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/08/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/08/10'))
```

上記の方法で作成すると、`closed`パラメータが指定されていないためデフォルトの`right`になって、`left`パラメータに指定した値は`Interval`に含まれないことになります。
[pandas.Interval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html)

> closed : {‘right’, ‘left’, ‘both’, ‘neither’}, default ‘right’
> Whether the interval is closed on the left-side, right-side, both or neither. See the Notes for more detailed explanation.

notes の記述に依れば期間は '2021/08/01' < Interval <= '2021/08/10' となります。
そうなると'2021/08/01'が含まれていないことになるため、`selected = df[df.index.contains('2021/08/01')]`は空のDataFrameになります。

'2021/08/01'を指定して'りんご'を含んだ行を抽出するためには、DataFrame作成時に以下のように`, closed='both'`を追加しておけば良いでしょう。

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={ '品名':[ 'りんご', 'バナナ', 'みかん' ] },
    index=[
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/08/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/08/10'), closed='both'),
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/09/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/09/10'), closed='both'),
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/10/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/10/10'), closed='both') ]
)
```

上記のようにDataFrameを作成することで、`pd.Timestamp('2021/08/01 00:01')`と言う風に捻り技を使うことなく、`df_out = df[df.index.contains('2021/08/01')]`で希望する行が抽出できるでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
closedキーワード引数を利用することで、
両端が閉じたIntervalオブジェクトを作成できました。

pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/08/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/08/10'), closed='both')

Answer (score 0):

ありがとうございます。
`index.contains()` を利用して抽出することで解決しました。

Pandasのindex系のAPIたくさんあるのですね。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={ '品名':[ 'りんご', 'バナナ', 'みかん' ] },
    index=[
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/08/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/08/10')),
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/09/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/09/10')),
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021/10/01'), pd.Timestamp('2021/10/10')) ]
)
display(df)

df_out = df[df.index.contains(pd.Timestamp('2021/08/01 00:01'))]
display(df_out)
```